# What is the ESLint rule to prevent newline after an object prop colon

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslintrc

I searched and search on both SO and Google. But I cannot find the rule to enforce this:

#### NOT OK

```
const object = {
  methods:
  {
  }
}
```

#### OK

```
const object = {
  methods: {
  }
}
```

It seems to not be [object-property-newline](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-property-newline) or [object-curly-newline](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-curly-newline)

### Edit:

it also doesn't seem to be [brace-style](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/brace-style).

[image]

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/brace-style

Comment: Thanks @Phil I updated the question. It seems to not be that one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no rule for that. You may propose this rule in to the eslint project, but I expect it would not be accepted.

In the meanwhile `eslint-plugin-prettier` do cover this case, but it is not possible to opt-in only this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Btw, Why would you expect it not to be accepted ?

Comment: My statement is unbased when I think of it.